# Jira - JQL Get all issues that are linked with any of my subtasks

Tags: jira, jql

Let's say that I have 3 issues: A, B (which is a subtask of A) and C, which is linked with B and isn't a subtask of A.

Now, being in issue A (current issue), I would like to do a JQL query to get all issues that are linked with any of my subtasks, and in this case it should give me C, as C is linked with B, which is a subtask of the current issue, A.

It would be nice if I could specify the issue link name and issue type of subtask.

I can use scriptrunner JQL and I tried using it but I still couldn't figure it.

Comment: Other users marked your question for low quality and need for improvement. I re-worded/formatted your input to make it easier to read/understand. Please review my changes to ensure they reflect your intentions. But I think your question is still not answerable. **You** should [edit] your question now, to include your own efforts  (see [help me is not a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question) ). Feel free to drop me a comment in case you have further questions or feedback for me.